# How to print a list of .pdf documents without opening them

Tags: bash, shell, macos

I have a list of files in the following format:

```
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
file3.pdf
...
```

how to print them on my printer without opening them

I can print a file with the command

```
lp file1.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can use `xargs` for that.

```
xargs --arg-file=argument-list.txt --delimiter='\n' <command>
```

It will read all lines from `argument-list.txt` and runs `<command>` with each line as an argument to command.

So if command is `lp` with your input file it would call it as `lp file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf ...`.